# select2 not working when in google maps fullscreen

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, jquery-select2

I have a google map that a user can go into fullscreen mode.  I add a div with a dropdown as controls to the map and I apply the select2 plugin to the dropdown.  The problem is the select2 dropdown doesn't show the list when the map is in fullscreen mode, when the map is not in fullscreen mode the dropdown works correctly.  There are no errors in the console.  I tried changing the z-index but had no luck.  Any ideas?

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/criverapr/net3ta5z/15/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=net3ta5z)

HTML

```
    <div id="wrapper">
  <div id="testMap">
  </div>
  <div id="inputControls" style="max-width: 275px">
    Select Country:
    <select id="testDropdownList" class="full-width">
      <option value="-1">-- Select --</option>
      <option value="1">Test 1</option>
      <option value="2">Test 2</option>
      <option value="3">Test 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

#inputControls {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 10px;
    top: 85px;
    left: -5px;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    z-index: 10;
    padding: 8px;
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-weight: normal;
    border-top-right-radius: 2px;
    border-top-left-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
}

#inputControls input {
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-family: Roboto;
}

#testMap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
    left: -15px;
}

#testDropdownList {
    font-size: 8pt;
}
```

JS

```
function initMap() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: {
      lat: 38.907192,
      lng: 17.036871
    },
    zoom: 2,
    fullscreenControl: true
  };

  testMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('testMap'), mapOptions);
  testMap.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP].push(document.getElementById('inputControls'));

}

$(document).ready(function() {


  initMap();

  $('#testDropdownList').select2({
    theme: "bootstrap"
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this script after page load:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("pac-container pac-logo hdpi")).forEach(function(item) {
   item.style.zIndex = 2147483647;
});
```