# Google Maps AutoComplete dropdown hidden when Google Maps Full Screen is true

Tags: google-maps, autocomplete, z-index, fullscreen, dropdown

I've implemented a google maps with autocomplete onverlayed on the map and I've set the FullScreenControl option to "true" (You can see the FullScreenControl on the right in the image below)

[image: AutoComplete DropDown hidden]

My problem is that when I switch to FullScreen mode by clicking the FullScreenControl, the dropdown is hidden behind the google map.
It seems that the ZIndex is too low but setting it to a very large number does not seem to fix the issue. You can see from the image below that the dropdown exists, but only behind the fullscreen google map.

I did find a similar question with answer where someone used a normal dropdown and not the google map autocomplete.
[Similar Question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41449002/select2-not-working-when-in-google-maps-fullscreen)

However the solution didn't work for me.
Setting the ZIndex doesn't seem to work.
I'm using TypeScript with Angular2.

Thank you.

[image: AutoComplete DropDown showing[![][2]]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxaOi.jpg)

Comment: try to change z-index .pac-container element

Comment: i have the same problem, change z-index doesn't work

Comment: Bug was reported: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/191279746

Comment: The z-index fix does not work for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix it by adding z-index to .pac-container

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41449002/select2-not-working-when-in-google-maps-fullscreen)

```
 .pac-container, .pac-item{
    z-index: 2147483647 !important;
 }
```

Comment: The z-index fix does not work for me

Answer (score 6):

For anyone struggling with this, if the z-index solution is not working:
The Google maps generated div ("pac-container") with the autocomplete options is appended to the body child elements. But when in full screen, only elements inside the target element (the map div) will be shown, so z-index is ignored.

A quick workaround is to move the pac-container div inside the map div when entering full screen, and move it back on exit.

```
document.onfullscreenchange = function ( event ) {
let target = event.target;
let pacContainerElements = document.getElementsByClassName("pac-container");
if (pacContainerElements.length > 0) {
    let pacContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("pac-container")[0];
    if (pacContainer.parentElement === target) {
        console.log("Exiting FULL SCREEN - moving pacContainer to body");
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(pacContainer);
    } else {
        console.log("Entering FULL SCREEN - moving pacContainer to target element");
        target.appendChild(pacContainer);
    }
} else {
    console.log("FULL SCREEN change - no pacContainer found");

}};
```

Comment: Thank you dearly. This is the solution I needed as I have a map in a modal.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you @vladhorby! I ended up with your solution due to updating z-index not working on my case. I got 1 little bug, somehow that options position not in the right place when on the fullscreen mode. I add little code to fix this thing. The idea is to add a class when in fullscreen mode, and delete that after leave the fullscreen. Hope this can help anyone with the same case.

```
document.onfullscreenchange = function ( event ) {
    let target = event.target;
    let pacContainerElements = document.getElementsByClassName("pac-container");
    if (pacContainerElements.length > 0) {
      let pacContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("pac-container")[0];
      if (pacContainer.parentElement === target) {
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(pacContainer);
        pacContainer.className += pacContainer.className.replace("fullscreen-pac-container", "");
      } else {
        target.appendChild(pacContainer);
        pacContainer.className += " fullscreen-pac-container";
      }
    }
  };
```

and the last thing add this to the your css file:

```
.fullscreen-pac-container[style]{
  z-index: 2547483647 !important;
  top:50px !important;
}
```